# How to append rank 1 tensors using only tensorflow operations?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensor

Say I have two rank 1 tensors of different (important) length:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
y = tf.constant([4, 5])
```

Now I want to append y to the end of x to give me the tensor:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)>
```

But I can't seem to figure out how.

I will be doing this inside a function that I will decorate with tf.function, and it is my understanding that everything needs to be tensorflow operations for the tf.function decorator to work. That is, converting x and y to numpy arrays and back to a tensor will cause problems.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The solution is to use tf.concat() as pointed out by @Andrey:

```
tf.concat([x, y], axis=0)
```

It turns out that the problem originated when trying to append a single number to the end of a rank 1 tensor as follows:

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
y = tf.constant(5)

tf.concat([x, y], axis=0)
```

which fails since here y is a rank 0 tensor of shape (). This can be solved by writing:

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
y = tf.constant([5])

tf.concat([x, y], axis=0)
```

since y will then be a rank 1 tensor of shape (1,).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.concat()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
t1 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
t2 = tf.constant([4, 5])
output = tf.concat([t1, t2], 0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey! I tried tf.concat at first, but I have now realized where the true problem lied. Will edit and clarify in the original post.